# How to add a field name as variable in Django?

Tags: python

Is it possible to pass in the field name instead of the hardcoded 'last_name'?

```
for item in queryset:
    to_json.append(item.last_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
for item in queryset:
    to_json.append(getattr(item, 'last_name'))
```

This allows `'last_name'` to be a variable instead of a hardcoded string.